# Python & translucent canvas

Tags: python, wxpython, tkinter, pygtk, toolkit

I'm looking for a way to draw real translucent lines with pygtk or wxPython, I now this is not possible with TKinter (I like this one because its already there). Also, I already now I can do this using PIL, but I want to draw direct to a canvas and it will be a dinamic content so I think using PIL will be a slow solution (and not elegant). Someone know a way to do this? Or maybe another toolkit that allows me to do this.

To get clear what I want is: If I drew lines with distinct colors that overlaps I need to be able to see both lines with a merged color at the intersection. Something like if the color I choose for the pen have a transparence instead of solid color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all "canvas" libraries have brushes with alpha.

- PyGTK has the [gtk.DrawingArea](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkdrawingarea.html), often used with [cairo](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/drawing/).
- [Cairo can be used with wxPython](http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingCairoWithWxPython) as well.
- QT has the [Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've tested Cairo with pygtk and it did what I need!! It's a lot of things to install windows on Windows but at the end it works!